# Cannot Enable Certificates

Tags: certificates, samsung-galaxy-j3

I've got a Samsung Galaxy J3 Prime running Oreo 8.1 that is getting NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID on literally every website, regardless of browser.  When I check the security certificates (Settings -> Security -> Other Security Settings -> View Security Settings) I see that every certificate is disabled and if I try to enable them they seems to disable again immediately.

I've tried multiple networks and applied all the updates I can with no luck.  This is a friend's phone so I don't know if any apps have been installed recently or anything.

Hopefully someone can think of something I have not.

Comment: Is the device rooted? has somebody tried to install a new certificate? Have you performed a factory reset (best from Android Settings menu).

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out why the certificates were greyed out, but I was able to re-enable them by tapping each one and using the enable button. For some reason the enable slider in the list didn't work, but tapping them and then tapping enable did.